# Unable to run react native code on Android using expo

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio, expo, metro-bundler

I'm new to react native using expo in the app, trying to run the app on android studio but getting some errors. when I try to run the app on web its working fine, but for android its giving error.

```
 Web is waiting on http://localhost:19000

› Press a │ open Android
› Press w │ open web

› Press j │ open debugger
› Press r │ reload app
› Press m │ toggle menu

› Press ? │ show all commands

Logs for your project will appear below. Press Ctrl+C to exit.
› Opening on Android...
Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: The system cannot find the path specified.
    at notFoundError (A:\Projects\xchange\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:6:26)
    at verifyENOENT (A:\Projects\xchange\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:40:16)
    at cp.emit (A:\Projects\xchange\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:27:25)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a file path error, I would suggest that you double check the ANDROID_HOME environment variables to make sure it is pointing correctly to the android SDK you have installed, following the guide at this link: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup . I would also advise that you check that you have installed the correct android SDKs when installing android studio.